# How to correctly declare and initialize enum attribute of a class?

Tags: typescript

I want to add an **enum** attribute to the class Character called `direction`. Value of **Up** should be 0, **Down** should be **1** and so on.

```js
export default class Character{
    public x: number;
    public y: number;

    // this syntax works.
    public animate: Boolean = true;

    // but this doesn't.
    public direction: enum = {
        UP,
        DOWN,
        LEFT,
        RIGHT
    };
 
    /* Then I tried this.
    public direction: enum {
        UP = 0,
        DOWN,
        LEFT,
        RIGHT
    };
    Got semicolon expected error.
    */


    constructor(x, y){
        
    }

}
```

Compiler shows the error message:

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'enum'.
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Why not declare the enum outside of the class? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAIglgJ2AYwC5wPYgKLmgbwCgoSoBVABSgF4oAGAGmNJgHkB1AOSdKgBlsAMQAqPUgCUAkgHEAEsMIBfANyFCwAB4AHDAlRQAJsABmAQzAAbfcgumAznagBhABamEptMARESzElpgAEYWcMhQGgBcUHhB3qq8gSFhUACe0bHxaonBoeGmIHAQpqjA0QBCGBgWwAU0UKgIYMAJ-lBJeYaIKOhY0fBIaJg4ePUDPcO4kAB0lMpQ2aTIWHaNYGi6ABQaDGkAlL68pG2KaopAA

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html - easy enough to Google!

Comment: @RakhaKanzKautsar For readability. I think it would have been better to limit its scope inside the class if possible. I was curious if there was any way to do this, like we have for other data types.

Comment: No, there is no other way. you have to define your enum as a separate object and then set this enum as type.